# Cut last n characters off of a String

Tags: pharo

Pharo beginner here - I've got some (ugly?) code that works for a specific case, but wonder if there's a better (more readable) way. I want to get the name of a repo without the .git at the end (if it's there).

Trimming off *n* characters would be great. I'm looking for a general solution.

I found `trimRight:` but it's not a number of characters; it's either white space or specific characters.

```
(projectName endsWith: '.git')
        ifTrue: [ projectName := projectName 
            copyFrom: 1 to: projectName size - '.git' size - 1 ]
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/3053685/1168342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`’Hello World’ allButLast: 2 => ‘Hello Wor’`

Answer (score 7):

For these cases where you want to remove a specific suffix if it is present, you have exactly #withoutSuffix:.

In your case, it should be

```
projectName withoutSuffix: '.git'
```